# 1366x768 laptop lcd and 1280x800 projecttor in clone mode

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, projector

We have a notebook with 1366x768 LCD screen, and the projector with interactive whiteboard has 1280x800 resolution. We use the laptop in screen clone mode to allow the lecturer to see the same projected content on the lcd as well (for example when she/he needs to type in the keyboard).
If the notebook set to clone display mode, it doesn't allow to choose 1280x800 resolution (the projector's native resolution). On the LCD should be seen a downscaled image, but I couldn't get it work.

I tried to add 1280x800 as a custom resolution but it won't allow anything that is higher than 768. 
It says: "custom resolution exceeds maximum bandwidth capacity"
(The projector has VGA. The OS is Windows 7 64-bit.)